# How to initialise and return an std::array within a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

I'd like a template function that returns some initialisation.

I did the following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>

template <typename T>
inline static constexpr T  SetValues()
{
    if(std::is_integral<T>::value)
    {
      std::cout<<"int\n";
      return T{1};
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout<<"array\n";
      T arr = {1,2,3,4};
      return arr;
    }
}


int main()
{
 int a = 6;
 std::array<int, 4> arr = {2,2,2,2};
 a = SetValues<decltype(a)>();
 arr = SetValues<decltype(arr)>();
 return 0;
}
```

which correctly initialises the int but in case of the array I get the error

> scalar object ‘arr’ requires one element in initializer

How should I initialise and return the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, when `T = int`, you're trying to trying to initialize `int arr` with initializer list `{1, 2, 3, 4}` in the `else` branch. Even if you don't execute the `else` branch, the compiler still has to compile it and `int arr = {1, 2, 3, 4}` is invalid syntax.

On C++17 (and higher), you can get away with `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename T>
inline static constexpr T SetValues() {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value) {
        std::cout << "int\n";
        return T{1};
    } else {
        std::cout << "array\n";
        T arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        return arr;
    }
}
```

With `if constexpr`, the compiler won't compile the `else` branch when `T` is an integral type (e.g. `int`) and will not compile the `if` branch when `T` is not an integral type.